# localStorage derived variable acts as integer when initally subtracting, but string when initally adding

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am having an issue in which an integer variable retrieved from LocalStorage will act abnormally depending upon which operation is first performed upon it.

If the first operation performed is a subtraction, the variable will act as an integer. Any further operations run as normal.

If the first operation performed is an addition, however, it will treat the variable as a string. Any further additions will treat it as a string as well, until the first subtraction operation is performed.

Here is the code in question (Forgive me for all of the alerts):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var line = 125;

    if (localStorage.getItem("gtLine") !== null) {
        line = localStorage.getItem("gtLine");
    }
    function shrink() {
        alert(line);

        line -= 10;

        alert(line);
        localStorage.setItem("gtLine", line);
    }
    function grow() {
        alert(line);

        line += 10;

        alert(line);
        localStorage.setItem("gtLine", line);
    }
    function reset() {
        line = 125;
        localStorage.setItem("gtLine", line);
        alert(line);
    }
</script>

<button onClick="javascript:shrink();">Shrink</button> 
<button onClick="javascript:grow();">Grow</button> 
<button onClick="javascript:reset();">reset</button>
```

And the steps in which to reproduce the problem:

First, press the shrink and grow buttons, in whatever order you see fit, to see that the script is working.

Then, refresh the page so that it reloads the variable from localStorage, press the shrink button, and then press the shrink and grow buttons, and see that they still work.

Now, refresh again, but this time press the grow button first. The grow function now treats the variable as a string, while the shrink function remains unchanged.

Comment: The value at `localStorage` is a stored as a string. `-=` operator casts `String` to `Number`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function 'localStorage.getItem' by default return value as 'String'. That's why it is doing concantenation while using '+'.
However, while doing '-' , it is type casting to int as there is not operation for String.

You are facing because javascript does typecasting directly as it is not strongly typed language.

```
'a' + 10 = a10
'11' + 10 = 110
'a'  - 10 = NaN
'11' - 10  = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that -= type casted it as an int.

Answer (score 0):

Because 
1) + sign is used for numerical addition and concatenation.
2) localStorage always stores data as string.
So after grabbing data from localStorage, you first type Cast your value. Then do your task on that value.

That will solve, any unwanted behavior of your code.

type Casting !!! is very useful.